# Is there any way to organize photos in the Photostream section of Flickr?

Tags: web, flickr

Is there any way to organize photos in the Photostream section of Flickr?  I would like to have it filled with folders with different groups of photos.  Instead, every photo I upload ends up in an unmanageable mess.  Let's say you have 1,000 photos uploaded, they're all right there with no organization.

Comment: Any reason you don't use albums instead of the photostream?

Comment: Are you using tags or other means of classification ?

Answer (score 5):

No.  Photostream is a view of all photographs in the account.  Flickr offers Albums, Galleries, and Collections, where you can arrange groups of photographs together as you'd like, but the photostream (and once it comes out of beta, the Camera Roll) will, according to Flickr staff comments, always be the full view of any photographs set to be publicly available.

Comment: it may be worth adding that the order that images appear in a photostream is controlled by image upload dates - and that there are [utilities](http://atastypixel.com/blog/sort-your-flickr-photostream/) that can manipulate this date to adjust the order